# Find the maximum & minimum value of complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3, \ldots, z_{13}$ be real numbers, & let $A$ be the average of 
complex numbers **$[e^{iz_1}, e^{iz_2}, \ldots ,e^{iz_{13}}]$**, where 
$i=\sqrt{-1}$.  As the value of **z's** vary over all 13-tuples of real numbers,

**Find:**

**i)** Maximum value attained by |A|.

**ii)** Minimum value attained by |A|.

My problem: I know that for a complex no, $x = a+ib$; $|x| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

But i can not figure out, how to compute **| average of the given set of complex no|** i.e, **|A|**.

Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: By triangle inequality, then, $$\lvert A\rvert\le\frac1{13}\sum_{k=1}^{13}\left\lvert e^{i z_k}\right\rvert.$$ Since each $z_k$ is real, what can you conclude?

**Edit**: The kicker, here, is to translate from polar form to rectangular form. In particular, given any real $t,$ we have that $$e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t,$$ and so Pythagorean Identity lets us explicitly find $\left\lvert e^{it}\right\rvert$ using the definition $\lvert a+ib\rvert=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: This summation equals 1/13[sigma{e^(zk^2)] (k=1 to 13). Now the summation is always a positive value because of the **powers of e cannot be negative**. Then how should i proceed?

Comment: Powers of $e$ can **certainly** be negative. *Real* powers of $e$ can't be negative, but these *aren't* real powers of $e$. Do you know any other forms for $e^{it}$ when $t$ is real? Perhaps something of the form $a+ib$?

Comment: No.I'm not enough good with complex numbers.

Comment: That's going to be absolutely essential for this exercise, I'm afraid. You're going to need to know how to write $e^z$ in rectangular form for general complex $z,$ or at least how to do it for $e^{iy}$ for real $y$. Check your text and notes to see what the connection is between polar and rectangular form.

Comment: Ok,i'm trying to find out the things you have mentioned.Thank you.

Comment: I have expanded on my answer to address the shortfall. (Sorry for the delay.)

Comment: Thanks. Yes i think i can.

Comment: if you find yourself stuck, feel free to let me know, and I'll see what I can do.